# Cubietruck USB is not working

Tags: android, embedded, usb

I am using a [Cubietruck](https://www.crazypi.com/CUBIEBOARD/CUBIEBOARD-CUBIETRUCK) with a Revision A A20 Dual Core chip with the OS given [here, version 1.00](http://docs.cubieboard.org/tutorials/cb3/installation/cubietruck_android-4.2.2_releases). There is also a 1.01 version, which I tried to flash onto it. It succeeded, but then I realized it was for the Revision B chip. I immediately re-flashed it with the 1.01 version. But now there is one problem - the USB on the Cubietruck does not work anymore. Any device I attach to it does not show any signs of even being powered on. For example, I have a mouse which lights up a LED when it receives power. When I plug it in, it does not work. It is the same for any device. I tried checking the solder joints on the USB connector but they were all fine. Any help/suggestions/have you got this bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you power your Cubietruck ? If you are using the USB OTG port, then the USB host ports are not powered.